# Categorical view on Skorokhod topology

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, category-theory

I often meet in literature on functional analysis or stochastic processes the following constructions.

Let $V$ be a vector space and $V_i \subseteq V$, $i \in I$ a family of locally convex spaces with $V = \bigcup_{i \in I} V_i$. If the topologies of the family $V_i$ are compatible (in the sense that $V_i \subseteq V_j$ then the induced topology from $V_j$ on $V_i$ coincides with the given topology on $V_i$) then one can define on $V$ the locally convex inductive limit topology such that the topologies of $\{ V_i \mid i \in I \} \cup \{ V \}$ are compatible.

As an example, this can be used to define the locally convex inductive limit topology on the space of compactly supported continuous functions $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ out of the family of subspaces that consist of continuous functions with support contained in a particular compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now consider the spaces of real-valued cadlag functions $D[a,b]$ and $D(\mathbb{R})$. Of course, with the usual Skorokhod topology these spaces are not topological vector spaces since addition is not continuous. But the topology on $D(\mathbb{R})$ is somehow constructed from the topologies on $D[a,b]$ by defining a metric on $D(\mathbb{R})$ in terms of integration over the metrics in $D([a,b])$. For simplicity let us consider the interval $[0, \infty)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. Then, if $f, g \in D([0, \infty))$ and $d_t$ is the metric in $D([0,t])$ then $d(f,g) := \int_0^\infty e^{-t} (d_t(r_t \circ f,r_t \circ g) \wedge 1) dt$ where $r_t$ are the restrictions to $D([0, t])$.

Is the topology on $D(\mathbb{R})$ also a kind of "inductive limit" (of course not a locally convex inductive limit which does not make sense here) or the categorical dual "projective limit"? If not, how would some inductive/projective limit topology look like? I think the purpose is the compatibility with the restrictions.

Comment: Well, so far I have found the following informations. On the space $C(I)$ of continuous functions the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets is the projective limit of the uniform topologies on $C(K)$ for compact $K \subseteq I$ (with projections $C(I) \to C(K)$ given by restrictions). The construction of the topology on $D(I)$ is similar except that it is not directly a projective limit since the restrictions $r_K : D(I) \to D(K)$ are not continuous everywhere ($r_K$ is continuous at $x \in D(I)$ if $x$ is continuous at the endpoints of $K$).

Comment: But is there some other way to view the topology on $D(I)$ by purely categorical constructions?

Comment: I for one have no idea what you're talking about when you say "of course," and I would guess that most of the category theory-minded people on here are in the same position-you might try rewriting this for an audience that doesn't know functional analysis. I also don't know what "cadlag" or "Skorokhod" mean, or what the wedging with $1$ in your integral signifies-I guess not the wedge product with the differential 0-form!

Comment: A function $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ on an interval $I$ is cadlag if it is right-continuous and has left-hand limits everywhere. Skorokhod invented several topologies on the set $D(I)$ of cadlag functions on $I$. The most prominent one is the $J_1$-topology (often just referred as the Skorokhod topology). This topology is Polish, i.e. separable and metrizable by a complete metric. This space is frequently used in the theory of stochastic processes. The $\wedge$-symbol is an abbreviation for the minimum (meet), i.e. $a \wedge b := \min(a,b)$.